# How to handle SCSS imports for an NPM package that require other SCSS npm modules?

Tags: css, node.js, angular, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I have created a custom library that has Bootstrap as a dependency. When I run npm install within my library, the `node_modules` folder is placed at the root level of the directory, and everything works fine. However, when I try to use the library as a dependency in other work – in this case an Angular 8 app – I get errors because the `node_modules` directory there is two levels up rather than one.

The library structure is:

```
ng-lib-ui
├── README.md
├── package.json
├── node_modules
└── styles
    ├── _bootstrap-imports.scss
    ├── _bootstrap-theming.scss
    ├── _fonts.scss
    ├── _icons.scss
    ├── _resets.scss
    ├── _type.scss
    ├── _utilities.scss
    ├── _variables.scss
    ├── index.scss
    └── mixins
```

My `bootstrap-imports` has the following `imports` from bootstrap:

```
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-grid.scss";
```

**The Question**: How should I handle this? I took a look at a couple of repos on Github, including [this one](https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-agency/tree/master/vendor), and it looks like they include Bootstrap in their `vendor` folder. Is the best way to handle this scenario really to just have Bootstrap in a `vendor` directory rather than including it as an NPM dependency?

Comment: Why do you use those imports? Just import from bootstrap and the module system should take care of finding the appropriate node_modules.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Need those imports there because they are used with the custom library we are putting on top of Bootstrap – for instance, Bootstrap's `media-breakpoint` mixins. What's more, we also change several Boostrap scss variables.

Comment: Sorry, that was unclear. I understand why you're importing from Bootstrap, but why *like that*? Can't you use the tilde imports?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've tried several variations of `@import '~node_modules/bootstrap/...'`, `@import  '~/node_modules/bootsrap/...'`, and `@import '~bootstrap/...'` but none seem to work. What's more, I looked at several Bootstrap theme repos, and none seem to use the ~.